# Accessing the static content in Spring 3 MVC application with integrated Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've created Spring 3 MVC project via Spring Tool Suite template and I have integrated Spring security there.. Everything works except accessing the static content.

When I create only MVC app and have my static content in `/src/webapp/WEB-INF/resources/`and put `<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/resources" />` to my `applicationContext.xml`, it works well...But I can't add this code to my `applicationContext.xml` with security...the code doesn't even compile..Any idea what to write to my web.xml to make this work?

My `applicationContext.xml` file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="cz.cvut.fit.genepi.controllers" />

<import resource="classpath:applicationContext-security.xml" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

It's weird that when using code above, mapping view-controller works allrigh, but when I'm using this, I get this error `The prefix mvc:resources is not bound`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="cz.cvut.fit.genepi.controllers" />
<import resource="classpath:applicationContext-security.xml" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

     </beans>
```

structure of the solution:

[image]

Comment: That code is not meant to be in `web.xml`, i think, it should be in your servlet context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code should be in your app context definition(applicationContext.xml), and the location is relative to deployment root :

```
 <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

you'll need this at top of config file

```
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
```

and then

```
 xsi:schemaLocation = http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
```

I think there may be someo confusion, the normal wdirectory structure is something like this:

```
src/main/java 
src/main/resources
src/main/webapp
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsps
src/main/webapp/css
```

The css directory is just an example, I acually have javascipt, and image directries as well, some people prefer just one called for example "static-assets". But calling it resources is rather confusing. The src/main/resource/ directory actually contains config files for the whole project (I put my appContext.xml's in there and log.properties files), it gets copied to WEB-INF on deployment and should not be used for mapping an static resources.
Eg, in my example  woul dactualyl be mapped like this :

```
<mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**"/>
```

Comment: I can't because I've already tried this and it's not working. I get Error: `The prefix mvc:resources is not bound`

Comment: now I've realized, that after adding `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` I can't access pages with controller. I get warning: `WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/fit/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
`

Comment: @Dworza your resources directory should be moved up one ... its the webapp directory that is the root directory on deployment.

Comment: I think, that it doesn't work thanks to the security :-/ Because in other project this works pretty well...

Comment: Security is another issue, you wouldn't get that error message.

Comment: I've edited my post, so you can see what changes in the servlet dispatcher I've made... As I say there - my previous version works just fine (except accessing the static content). The other allows me to access static content on pages without controller, nevertheless I can't access pages with controller :D now it would be nice to merge those two.. :D

Comment: @Dworza where is your resources located on the filesystem ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26618/discussion-between-nimchimpsky-and-dworza)

Comment: @Dworza you simply don;t hav ea request mapped to /fit/ ?#

Comment: Of course I do...As I've said, it used to work just fine before..but after adding <mvc:resources .... ..../> it all crashes down :-/

Comment: @Dworza <mvc:annotation-driven/> as well needed in config, before resource mapping

Comment: Omg! You're right! How could I miss that?! :D Thank you very much budy!